# SpeechRecognizer windows phone without network connection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

I'm wondering is there a way NOT to have a network connection in order to implement a SpeechRecognizer on a app i'm building that should allow me to speak to it and run code from my speech? If not, Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can try to integrate CMUSphinx engine in your phone http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net. I know few people who ported it to WP8 and it worked well offline for keyword activation and command recognition.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use the Visual Studio Emulator

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: I'm pretty knew to the Wp dev thing so I wouldn't know where to begin. I assumed you'd needed to have a windows phone